# Unable to git clone from github in remote host

Tags: git, github, ssh

This is my situation.

I was added to a private repo in Github.

I cloned it and I'm able to `git push` normally in my local environment.

In my remote host, I imported my ssh key and I can ssh into it without having to type a password.

But while in remote host, if I do `git clone` I receive the error `Permission denied (publickey)`.

This error also happens if I try `git clone` with `ssh://` and `https://`.

In my local host if I do `ssh -T git@github.com` it tells me I'm successfully authenticated, if I do it in the remote host, then back to `Permission denied (publickey)`.

Does Github needs something more than my ssh key?
If I'm able to log into the ssh without having to type a password, this clearly means the ssh key works. **But then why would Github deny it only in remote?**

Comment: Do you have the key on the remote host? Do you have the key in the `ssh-agent`? How do you connect to the `remote` host?

Comment: @user2094178 : Have you configured `git config --global user.name` and `git config --global user.email` ?

Comment: @Shravan40 In the remote host? No.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to enable forwardAgent, so the remote host can use your key while you're loggued on.

To try that, just disconnect from the host, and reconnect with the `-A` flag :

```
ssh -A myremotehost
```

Then, try to clone your repos normally:

```
git clone ...
```

Another way to fix that is to generate a key for the remote host and add it to the github repos.